# What notation should I use for a set matrices of different size?

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, notation

I have $N$ data points where each is a 2-D matrix $\mathbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times*}$ which means that they are different in their second dimension. I want to use a notation to recall them all together, for instance as an input argument to a function or an algorithm.

I may use $\{\mathbf{Y}^i\}_{i=1}^N$ to show I mean all of them and $\mathbf{Y}^i$ to denote the $i$th matrix. But, I prefer a more condensed notation. Otherwise, I need to use it for example like 
$$K=f(\{\mathbf{Y}^i\}_{i=1}^N)$$
which may not look so nice!

Comment: Unless you want to specify a particular (sub)set/sequence of second dimensions, there is no need to qualify $Y$ with that. So you essentially pass a set of "items".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ${\bf Y}$ for your full data set. This ${\bf Y}$ has $N$  components $Y_i$ $(1\leq i\leq N)$ corresponding to the $N$ data points,  each of these being a matrix $Y_i\in{\mathbb R}^{d\times n_i}$. Then you can talk about $K=f({\bf Y})$.